# Role of economic developement in political stability?

Tags: economy, political-system

Often it is given that rapid economic progress is one the things that make the Chinese communist party acceptable to the Chinese people. Can this be accepted as a given fact? Conversely, if there was rapid improvement of quality of life in a country in a given period of time, would that increase the political stability of a country?

Comment: It's the old "he made the trains run on time" thing. Dictatorships can be very efficient governments, but and citizens who judge based on these superficial benefits will often accept the poor civil rights as a necessary evil.

Comment: While it is true that good economy will keep unrest low, it is not something universally true. The cultural and international context of the country plays a huge rule. E. G. Being a nuclear power, it is unlikely the international scene would let China fall into disarray. The same can't be said about Congo, for example.

Comment: @Barmar I think it's less a question of "necessary evil" than of "easy to overlook if you don't rock the boat."  If the poor civil rights consist of "criticizing the party will get you arrested," and you have no criticism of the party, then you just don't have much to worry about.  If you have a good education, a nice place to live, good health care, and so on, why complain?

Answer (score 4):

> **Question 1:**
>
> Often it is given that rapid economic progress is one the things that make the Chinese communist party acceptable to the Chinese people. Can this be accepted as a given fact?

I agree that it is common wisdom that the CCP is only kept in power because it delivers economic progress.  As for this being accepted as a given fact, I don't see how it could; given the the CCP control predates China's economic emergence.  They have also been primarily responsible for catastrophic massacres and and atrocities which have lead to national impoverishment. These occurring prior to their economic emergence; and didn't result in the CCP losing power.

- Great Leap Forward
- Cultural Revolution

> **Question 2:**
>
> Conversely, if there was rapid improvement of quality of life in a country in a given period of time, would that increase the political stability of a country?

**Short Answer:**

Rapid typically isn't a good word when discussing economics.  There is a sweet spot for economic growth which improves the quality of life.  Not all growth does so.  How much pain, and how much growth is reasonable are functions of what stage a country is in it's economic development.

**Answer:**

Manageable economic growth 1-4% improves the quality of life in a country.  Typically large rapid sustained growth creates instability and over the near term strains a county's social, legal, and economic infrastructure.

Take the **[U.S. economy](https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2023/08/23/americas-astonishing-economic-growth-goes-up-another-gear)** by some estimates currently growing at 6%.  That would seem to be spectacular, only it's not.  It's not sustainable and promotes instability.  In the long run it's better to grow slower longer than rapidly for a shorter period of time.  So the U.S. federal reserve is raising interest rates to bring growth down to a more manageable 2-3-4% ambitious sweet spot.

Typically under capitalism rapid economic improvement, meaning decades of double digit growth in GDP as China has experienced isn't predicated on "stability", in fact it causes instability.  Think of the US in the 1880's - 1920's, when it was an economically emerging country with decades of double digit growth in GDP.  The rapid economic improvement lead to:

- The Rise of the **[robber baron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robber_baron_(industrialist))** class

Historian John Tipple examined the writings of the 50 most influential analysts who used the robber baron model in the 1865–1914 period. He argued:

> The originators of the Robber Baron concept were not the injured, the poor, the faddists, the jealous, or a dispossessed elite, but rather a frustrated group of observers led at last by protracted years of harsh depression to believe that the American dream of abundant prosperity for all was a hopeless myth. ... Thus the creation of the Robber Baron stereotype seems to have been the product of an impulsive popular attempt to explain the shift in the structure of American society in terms of the obvious. Rather than make the effort to understand the intricate processes of change, most critics appeared to slip into the easy vulgarizations of the "devil-view" of history which ingenuously assumes that all human misfortunes can be traced to the machinations of an easily located set of villains—in this case, the big businessmen of America. This assumption was clearly implicit in almost all of the criticism of the period.

- **[concentration of wealth](https://time.com/5122375/american-inequality-gilded-age/)**

in 1897

> the richest 4,000 families in the U.S. (representing less than 1% of the population had about as much wealth as rest of the nation

- systemic corruption

  - **[How the Gilded Age’s Top 1 Percent Thrived on Corruption](https://www.history.com/news/gilded-age-corruption-corporate-wealth)**
  - Richard White, professor emeritus of history at Stanford University and author of **[The Republic for Which It Stands: The United States During Reconstruction and the Gilded Age, 1865-1896](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199735816)**, says the Gilded Age was among the most corrupt eras in American history primarily because of “the rise of corporations and the growth of modern means of communication that intensified the way corruption can work.”
- extreme poverty
- lawlessness
- private armies

  - The Pinkerton's had more men and guns in 1919 than the U.S. Army.
- massacres

  - 1919 Pinkerton's at Pittsburg **[homestead massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homestead_strike)**
  - 1921 West Virginia's **[Battle of Blair Mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Blair_Mountain)**

The typical capitalistic model is after extreme exploitation, labor organizes and makes the status quo unprofitable.   This typically occurs not in the extreme growth / emerging phase of the economic life cycle.  This typically get's sorted out in the economic adolescence.  When growth slows and systems must be optimized to exist with 1 or 2% growth rather than with 10-20% growth.  Reforms are introduced to make labor and management partners in growth.  Capitalism transforms to more of a mixed market system.  Not every county successfully navigates this transition,  those that do can take decades to advanced to economic maturity or fall backwards economically.

Now China isn't typical.  China is trying something different in the industrial age.  They are trying to industrialize and go through rapid expansion while simultaneously lifting people out of poverty.  They have published poverty numbers which suggest they're being very successful.

**[China lifts 800m people out of poverty over 40 years, accounting for 75% of global poverty reduction](https://www.globaltimes.cn/page/202203/1257339.shtml)**

Problems are:

- Global Times is a Chinese state media organization without any creditability
- China regularly exaggerates numbers.

Given what we read about religious persecutions, Fulun Gong, and the Uyghurs treatment:  forced labor, organ harvesting,  mass incarceration, mass murder, sexual assaults. it seems like China too is facing great unrest challenges during it's economic assentation, only in their case it's a centrally planned systemic crisis rather than one of a more localized systemic nature.